# Jquery UI tooltip doesn't show on anything

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker, jquery-ui-tooltip

I'm working with 2 bootstrap datepickers and
I want to verify if the start date is greater than the end date then show a tooltip

Here's what I have so far :

http://jsfiddle.net/k84phas6/

`$('#startdate_datepicker').tooltip({ content : "Example"});`

Alert is showing up but the tooltip doesn't do anything and I don't understand why.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just checked your fiddle, There are multiple places where you have to make changes.

1. Remove the title="" field from your input box. This is colliding with the tooltip's title field which bootstrap uses.
2. As above answer suggests you have to programmatically trigger it to show.

your code will look like following

here is modified fiddle of yours http://jsfiddle.net/b7urzdxj/

```
//title removed
<input class="form-control start_date" type="text" placeholder="Start Date" name="startdate_datepicker" id="startdate_datepicker" required="true">

//tooltip modified and programmatically triggered

 if (start > end) {
    e.preventDefault();
        alert("Stop and tooltip");
    $('#startdate_datepicker').tooltip({ title : "Example", placement:'bottom'});
    $('#startdate_datepicker').tooltip('show')
  }
```

Comment: Thanks ! Works fine, strange that the jquery doc about tooltip doesn't mention that you have to put a tooltip('show') at the end. Even in the examples they just put a title in the input and then $("#tooltip").tooltip();
Is it because of bootstrap ?

Answer (score 1):

Add `data-toggle="tooltip"` and `data-trigger="manual"` attributes along with `title` on your **startdate_datepicker** element and then toggle the tooltip from JS by calling `tooltip() method` with "toggle" as parameter. Added the code snippet below:

**HTML startdate_datepicker element:**

```
<input class="form-control start_date" type="text" placeholder="Start Date" name="startdate_datepicker" id="startdate_datepicker" required="true" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Tooltip on bottom" data-trigger="manual">
```

**JavaScript:**

```
if (start > end) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // alert("Stop and tooltip");
    $('#startdate_datepicker').tooltip("toggle");
}
```

find the [fiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/d6t5wsnx/18/#&togetherjs=Pbe3RABgis)

Comment: Thanks works fine. What's best ? Putting data-toggle, placement, title, etc in the input or add the title with the tooltip then show it ?

Comment: put all the static element like data-toggle, placement etc. in the input to reduce the JS code, in case of title if it's dynamic, then pass it from JS code.

Answer (score 0):

Now you are initing tooltip for that input. You need to open tooltip manually after init like this:

```
$("#startdate_datepicker").tooltip({
   content: "Message!"
}).tooltip("open");
```